# Custom admin page for Custom Post Type when there is not any post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to display an import button for my custom post type dashboard when there is no post type. By default WordPress displays a table with content "No custom post found". Basically I want to do like the WooCommerce does, when we install WooCommerce and there is no product, in products list they display only an Import button like screenshot.

[image]

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: So I have to post this question again on that site?